# Calling C# function with multiple arguments from F#

Tags: .net, f#

It is easy to call `f:Func<'T, 'T>` from F# as `'T -> 'T` by using `f.Invoke`

But how should I call `f:Func<'T, 'T, 'T>` from F# as `'T -> 'T -> 'T`?

When I use `f.Invoke` I get `'T * 'T -> 'T`, i.e. a tuple instead of two arguments.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try:

```
let g = f.Invoke |> FuncConvert.FuncFromTupled
```

Answer (score 8):

Note that you do not need to turn the function into a function taking two arguments if you just want to call it.
If you already know the arguments for the function, then you can just call it as a function taking a tuple:

```
f.Invoke(40, 2)
```

Converting the `Func<T1, T2, R>` delegate to a function `'T1 -> 'T2 -> 'R` is still useful though, if you need to pass it to some code that expects a curried function (multiple-argument function) of this type. But even then, you can write that using an explicit lambda:

```
functionTakingTwoArgumentFunc (fun a b -> f.Invoke(a, b))
```

... and this is exactly what `FuncConvert.FuncFromTupled` does.

Comment: Thanks! A curried function was the case