# Func<T, TResult> property in F#

Tags: c#, f#

I am currently interoperating with C# code from F#.

Is it possible in F# to define a property that in C# looks like below?

`private Func<PropertyInfo, bool> OnIsSatisfiedByProperty { get; set; }`

(In F# it wouldn't have to be `Func<T, TResult>` but something equivalent.)

Comment: Any further info? i.e. is this really `protected` or `public` ? Are you declaring in F# an interface that will be used from C#? How will you initialize it? Is having an actual getter or setter method important? Do you care about the setter having a guard clause? In the absence of further context, my default answer would be `let private mutable OnIsSatisfiedByProperty : (PropertyInfo -> bool) option = None`. Then you can use `Option.iter` et.al to remove null checks. Or you can work by having it as a primary ctor arg: `type X( ?OnIsSatisfiedByProperty) = ...` if mutability is not of value

Comment: @RubenBartelink It could be declared as internal but that's not really important in my scenario. It is actually a Test Type. The value could be supplied using Constructor Injection but idiomatically for such Test Types I do it using Object Initializers.

Comment: So, can we assume you are declaring the test type in F# and then need it to be initializable from C# and hence it's not a matter of 'could be' `internal` - you need it to be `public`/`internal` and not `private`? If so, the static types become pretty important; @John Palmer's answer (and my comment) creates an `FSharpFunc<PropertyInfo,bool>` hence his contortions re having to init.

Comment: The Test Type is defined in F# and it will be used from F#. The design is C#-ish (and I have also a working example in C#, hence the initial interoperability) - Right now I follow the OO design first to see the test passing and then, I think, I will slowly move to a more FP paradigm.

Comment: Fair enough - ultimately if you need/want a public setter then a `val` is the way to go. But I'd be looking to move to a `type test( onIsSatisfiedByProperty? ) =` structure to be able to lean on `Option`.* - obv it depends on the exact nature of your real interop requirementss though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the equivalent would be something like

```
type test() = 
        member val private OnIsSatisfiedByProperty:PropertyInfo -> bool = (fun _ -> true) with get,set;;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. This seems to work out of the box :)

Answer (score 5):

If you need to interop with the type from C#, you def want it to be a `Func<T>` as opposed to `FSharpFunc` which has extra metadata such as non-`null` stipulations [as my earlier comments and @John Palmer's answer ends up being]. Hence the shortest similar actual equivalent you can init with an object-initializer is:

```
type MyType()=
    member val public OnIsSatisfiedByProperty : Func<PropertyInfo,bool> = null with get,set
```

or you could go down the route of:

```
type MyType()=
    [<DefaultValue()>]val mutable OnIsSatisfiedByProperty : Func<System.Reflection.PropertyInfo,bool>
```

but my quick messing about leaves me needing to impl explicit set/get methods in that case.

(BTW I knew this answer only due to conincidentally a few mins back, a `fixture.Inject( fun () -> !value)` wasnt working the same way as `fixture.Inject<Func<MyValue>>( fun () -> !value)` !)

Comment: Given the following [code](https://gist.github.com/moodmosaic/7775783), [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20325527/467754) seems to work. I tried to apply the snippets you provided but the code didn't compile... :/

Comment: @NikosBaxevanis will look later. Can't say I tested them or ILSpyed them but there were no squigglies and FSI processed them.... :)

Comment: @NikosBaxevanis If you're talking about not being to apply the  `Func`, you need a `.Invoke` on the end... But I guess if it works the other way, there are def pros (hence my +1 on it). I guess a `cinst ILSpy`  should tell you everything you need to know. See also [FuncConvert and associated stuff](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19290920/11635)

Comment: Oh, I see :) No problem. Thanks a lot for the help. I set [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20325527/467754) as accepted since it worked out of the box with the existing gist I had.

Comment: @NikosBaxevanis Yes, that's fair - if you don't need stuff to be exposed as a Func<T> there's no need. Good that you have it resolved...